# template option missing at wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, templates

I am very new at wordpress theme development. I am  facing  a problem over and again. The problem is the below . **template** option missing at wordpress dashboard.how can i visible **template** option at wordpress dashboard.

[image: dashboard]

Comment: Do you have `/* Template Name: ... */` in your template file as described here - https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates ? Also, what is your template's filename ?

Comment: i used  /* Template Name: ... */ at my template file . template file name 'welcome-template.php'

Answer (score 1):

first you need to create a template,then after it will show in dashboard

```
   <?php 
    /*  
     Template Name: My Custom Page 
    */ 
   ?>
```

put the code on your template file and check you will see the option